# OSM Overpass query along track from QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api

Is there a way to do an Overpass query along a track (from GPX generated vector layer)? I want to get some features on and around a river.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer of @mmd you can use the following python code to create the around statement. Just import the GPX as a feature layer and select one single line.

```py
# Get selected feature
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()
if (len(selected_features) > 1 or len(selected_features) == 0):
   raise Exception('One feature should be selected!')
selected_feature = selected_features[0]

# Create Query String
geometry = selected_feature.geometry()
latLngPairs = []
for part in geometry.parts():
    for v in part.vertices():
        latLngPairs.append(str(round(v.y(),7)) + ',' + str(round(v.x(),7)))

queryString = '(around:10,' + ','.join(latLngPairs) + ')'
print(queryString)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Additional code how you can directly load the query as a new feature layer.

```py
import requests
import json
import urllib.parse

# Get selected feature
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()
if (len(selected_features) > 1 or len(selected_features) == 0):
   raise Exception('One feature should be selected!')
selected_feature = selected_features[0]

# Create overpass query String
geometry = selected_feature.geometry()
latLngPairs = []
for part in geometry.parts():
    for v in part.vertices():
        latLngPairs.append(str(round(v.y(),7)) + ',' + str(round(v.x(),7)))

aroundQuery = 'around:10,' + ','.join(latLngPairs)
queryString = ('[out:json];(node('+ aroundQuery +')["highway" = "bus_stop"];(._;>;););convert item ::=::,::geom=geom(),_osm_type=type();out geom;')
queryObj = {'data': queryString}

# Make Request to overpass
overpassUrl = 'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter'
response = requests.post(overpassUrl, data = queryObj)
result = response.json()
geojsonResult = result["elements"]

# Create Result Geojson and add to map
featureCollection = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': geojsonResult
}

overpassResult = QgsVectorLayer(json.dumps(featureCollection), "overpassResult", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(overpassResult)
```

Comment: You should probably simplify raw GPS traces by applying Douglas-Peucker to reduce the data volume and improve the overall query performance. 7 digits should be sufficient as well, see https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: Good remark - although I don't get it what you want to tell me with the link. I just updated the python code to round to 7 decimal places.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also for the additional code. If i want also way and relation, i only have to double the line `queryString = ('[out:json];(node('+ aroundQuery +')["highway" = "bus_stop"];(._;>;););convert item ::=::,::geom=geom(),_osm_type=type();out geom;')
`? Are you sure you dont want to write a plugin? :)

Comment: There is actually a very good plugin already available: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/

Comment: But I think they do not support around queries with LINESTRING WKT - maybe patching this plugin is worth having a look.

Comment: They support only points. I had a parallel discussion on Github: https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/issues/403#issuecomment-1121029233 and did a feature request: https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/issues/404

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the Overpass QL around statement along with a list of lat/lon pairs. More details are also available in the Overpass QL documentation: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Relative_to_other_elements_(around)

I wrote a blog post on this topic wth some further example code and screenshots: https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/mmd/diary/42055

Example: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1iij

```
way[highway](around:500,50.540853270068986,8.048780365649707,50.53106288705902,8.030823236553783,50.51780737956311,8.019643105996508,50.50287491071276,8.016749912560886,50.48828159051387,8.022534398052139,50.47599950382573,8.036215335651725,50.467689755650376,8.055945038928135,50.46447690759688,8.079058902127825,50.46679590711731,8.102435269947343,50.47433280529453,8.122917034379736,50.48606755168466,8.137738019645033,50.50041288059356,8.144896569557243,50.51542994506574,8.143425882283827,50.529090915610794,8.13352458229042,50.53955268865336,8.11652989500613,50.545404823255616,8.09473704711951,50.545858734919165,8.07108928349599,50.540853270068986,8.048780365649707);(._;>;);out meta;
```

Some performance hints

- You should simplify / de-noise your GPS traces before feeding it into (around: ). Don't just translate your raw GPS traces into a query, otherwise query performance will be really poor.
- 7 digits should be more than sufficient (yes, example needs some rework).

Comment: Could you please include relevant code in you answer, instead of only linking it, since links are subject to change. Thank you =)